# get the call back of vs-dropdown open and close in vue js from vuesax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuesax

i am using [vs-dropdown](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax/blob/master/src/components/vsDropDown/vsDropDownMenu.vue) like below

```
    <vs-dropdown vs-custom-content vs-trigger-click class="cursor-pointer"  @click="dropdownClick($event)">
<feather-icon icon="BellIcon" class="cursor-pointer mt-1 sm:mr-6 mr-2" :badge="5" />

         <vs-dropdown-menu class="notification-dropdown dropdown-custom vx-navbar-dropdown">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
          </vs-dropdown-menu>
    </vs-dropdown>
```

in methods

```
dropdownClick(event) {
          console.log("dropdownClick", event)  # undefined in the console and this method getting called two times  
},
```

so how get callback like opened or closed when vs-dropdown click?

Comment: Can you post your whole dropdown code?  This would not show anything because there is no button

Comment: https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/documentation/components/dropDown.html#default

Comment: When `vs-button` is alone, `@click` works properly, but not inside the dropdown, yet that's how the examples show it.  So it seems they don't expect you to use `@click` with it.  What do you need it to do besides show the dropdown anyway?

Comment: @Dan it is working fine like when i click bell icon dropdown is opening if i click again it is closing, but i want trigger some function when dropdown opens, how to?

Comment: It seems bugged so I guess you'll have to ignore every 2nd event.  As I said, it seems they don't expect you to trigger anything when the dropdown opens.  What do you want to trigger?  I can't think of any reason to trigger something when a dropdown opens

Comment: @Dan because I have to delete all message in DB so I need to call API when the drop-down opens for this I need a callback when the dropdown open but not on close